# Populate mailto link using REST

Tags: rest

I have only had experience with using REST in a SPD workflow.  How can I use jQuery with REST to have a user click a button and open up a `mailto:` link and have that link mail to the users returned from the REST call.

I have the query that I need, I just need to learn how to use it with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add jQuery references to the Page as below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/jquery-min.js"></script>
```

Now you can activate a REST call as follows

```
var url = RESTQUERY;

jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",    
    headers: { 
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function(d) {
        var stringData = JSON.stringify(d);
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(stringData);
        var results = jsonObject.d.results;
        for(i = 0; i < results.length;i++) {
            console.log(results[i]["Member"]["EMail"]) 
            //HERE YOU CAN FORM THE MAIL TO LINK
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('fail');
    }
});
```

Comment: I've almost got it returning what I need.  In the console, it brings back the object, which is a person field.  I need to grab the email from that field.  I can get it in my REST query, but what do I put in the field name to expand on `"Member"`? (`Member` would be in place of `Title` in your example)

Comment: Can you post the rest query, here.. Are you using `$select` then use the same as the field name.

Comment: This is my query `<MySite>/_api/lists/getbytitle('My List')/items?$select=Member/EMail&$expand=Member`

Comment: Try `Email` as the field name.. Also when you put the query in browser you will get something like `d:Email` so whatever following `d:` should be used.

Comment: I get `undefined` if I use `Email`.  In the console, it gets returned in the object of `Member` when I use that.  Can I do more with that to grab it?

Comment: If you try the query in browser, how the email is returned? What is the property name?

Comment: `<m:properties><d:EMail>`. I tried both `Email` and `EMail`, neither worked.

Comment: Ok use the same case `EMail` and not `Email`.

Comment: I tried both, edit above.

Comment: You should do trial and error to get the correct syntax. Try `results[i].Member.EMail` or `results[i].Member["Email"]` etc.

Comment: Got this to work. Updated your answer to show correct syntax of `console.log(results[i]["Member"]["EMail"])`